# (a) Prove that $f_n(x) → f(x)$ uniformly on $E$ as $n → ∞.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E ⊂ R$ be a compact (i.e., closed bounded) set of real numbers. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of real-valued continuous functions which converges pointwise on $E$ to a function $f$ that is also continuous on $E.$ Suppose further that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is monotonic: $f_{n+1}(x) ≤ f_n(x)$ for all $x ∈ E$ and all $n = 1,2,....$
(a) Prove that $f_n(x) → f(x)$ uniformly on $E$ as $n → ∞.$
(b) Show by example that the hypothesis of compactness is essential.

We have that each of the $f_n$ and the $f$ is uniformly continuous, which I thought may be useful, but am not exactly sure how.

Comment: This is the Dini theorem. You can find the proof in a book of real analysis =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example that compactness is essential:

Take $f_n(x)=\chi_{[0,n]}$.

To do the original proof, have a look at [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem). (My proof would be exactly same as given here- so I didn't bother writing it out.)

Comment: Your $f_n$ is not continuous.

Comment: @Thursday: That's not a big deal- you can "smoothen" $f_n$'s to get sequence of continuous functions- this is a standard trick.